# how to make sure that my js run after directive loaded in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have a directive which renders a view template and some js code in my main page which tries to get some element in my view template. And since the js code is executed before the template rendered, the will always be undefined error like

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
<test></test>
<script src="angular.js"></script>
<script src="directives.js"></script>
<script>
    //try to get an element in directive and failed
    alert(document.getElementById('testdiv').innerHTML);
</script>
</body>
```

simple in directive.js

```
angular.module('myApp', []).directive('test', function(){
  return {
      restrict: 'E',
      template: '<div id="testdiv">Hello</div>'
  }
});
```

I am not very familiar with angular and your help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Once you start using AnuglarJS you should avoid running direct JS code. Can you give some more details around your scenario. Once you have created directive why not use it's link function to manipulate DOM

Comment: Thanks Chandermani! My scenario is that I am converting a 'classic' application into a angularjs based one. I have a jquery based custom.js file having business with dom elements.(handling animation, dom replacing and some other things). Now these dom elements have been put into separate templates and I don't want to change the custom.js file. I want these templates loaded, then call the custom.js

Answer (score 1):

Put your code in JavaScript function attach() and call attach() function from Link function 
in your directive

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
<test></test>
<script src="angular.js"></script>
<script src="directives.js"></script>
<script>
    //try to get an element in directive and failed
   function attach()
   { 
    alert(document.getElementById('testdiv').innerHTML);
   }
</script>
</body>
```

Directive Code:

```
angular.module('myApp', []).directive('test', function(){
  return {
      restrict: 'E',
      template: '<div id="testdiv">Hello</div>', 
      link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
       attach()
      }

  }
});
```